# HAML - not sure why a compile error happens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have this HAML

```
-content_for :primary_content do
  #available-disclosures-container
    .message-container.information-container
      %h3=(t "headings.influencers.disclosures.new")
      %p=raw((t "influencers.instructions.disclosures.new"))
    =render "sidebar/disclosures/list", :disclosures => Disclosure.basics, :show_link => true, :selectable => true, :usable => false

  #disclosure-form-container{:style => "display:none;"}
    = form_for([:sidebar,@disclosure], :html => {:id => "disclosure-form", :remote => true}) do |f|
```

I am not sure why, but this last line:

```
= form_for([:sidebar,@disclosure], :html => {:id => "disclosure-form", :remote => true}) do |f|
```

is causing this error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

and

```
6:     =render "sidebar/disclosures/list", :disclosures => Disclosure.basics, :show_link => true, :selectable => true, :usable => false
7: 
8:   #disclosure-form-container{:style => "display:none;"}
9:     = form_for([:sidebar,@disclosure], :html => {:id => "disclosure-form", :remote => true}) do |f|
10:       %p
11:         =f.label :display_as, (t :select_disclosure_type)
12:         =f.select :display_as, options_from_collection_for_select(Disclosure.basics, :display_as, :name, f.object.display_as)
```

Any idea what element is causing this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it because of the @disclosure object that I somehow need to make the system aware of it?

Comment: Check your controller. Does it set the `@disclosure` variable? If it doesn't then you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
= form_for([:sidebar, @disclosure]) do |f|
```

It looks like you're trying to generate the route by using the sidebar symbol which would need to be an instance of a model which disclosure belongs to in order to work.

Hard to know for sure but maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
= form_for(@disclosure), :url => [:sidebar, @disclosure] do |f|
```